# Search Form Error sends to ?q=

Tags: php, forms, search

I'm using Bootstrap theme and my form is this:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" action="<?=$domain?>search" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" placeholder="Search" name="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The original page where is placed is

http://www.domain.com/toys/search/Electronics for Kids/

when i search into form "test" and press enter, it sends me to

http://www.domain.com/toys/search/?q=test

With what should i replace the code to send me to:

http://www.domain.com/toys/search/test

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use JQuery if you use bootstrap.

So do following:

HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" action="<?=$domain?>search" id="searchFrom">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="searchField" class="form-control input" placeholder="Search" name="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('submit','#searchFrom', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = $(this).attr('action')+'/'+encodeURIComponent($('#searchField').val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, to be honest i don't know where to put the JS code that you've send to me.

Comment: I see that my theme use external JS from     <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: The search field value should be put through `encodeURIComponent` to avoid unexpected results (e.g. if the search string contains `?` or `&`).

Comment: Thank tarleb for comming by, can you please write me an answer with code? Thanks agian!

Comment: I tried to edit the answer, but the edit was rejected.  Just replace the above line containing the `location.href=…` with `location.href = $(this).attr('action')+'/'+encodeURIComponent($('#searchField').val());`

Comment: Edited the answer for encoding! To add the JS Code, search the Code where your JS-Files are loaded, and add a new File there with your JS-Code!